# Autohotkey get position of current link

Tags: autohotkey

If you navigate a webpage with Tab and shift-Tab

Is there any way to get the X,Y position of the currently marked link? 
(been googling this all afternoon) :P

Comment: What do you mean with "The currently marked link"? Try to be more verbose and explain what you are looking for.

Comment: If you tab trough a webpage Tab moves a marker from link to link. Instead of pressing Enter to visit the link, i want to get its position, or any way to select the link text.

Comment: A bit like when (in Chrome) you have tabbed to a link, and you press the right menu key (to the right of the space bar) and you select "Inspect Element" where you get background data (no XY coordinates) on the html code.

Comment: Ah! theres something called "Caret Browsing" in acessability. Seems to do what i want in IE

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

MsgBox, %A_CaretX% %a_carety%

Comment: ah ok, chrome seems limited when navigating with keyboard.